# Word 2007 - Pasted Text Not Spellchecked?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

My Word 2007 spell-check seems to work fine, except that when I paste in text from somewhere else, it won't detect any misspellings in that pasted text...no matter what I try.

If it makes any difference, when I paste in text, the formatting is preserved (size color etc).

Any ideas on what to try?

Comment: This is more Super User material.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Paste Special and do it as text, then you will be able to spell check it.  Otherwise I believe there is formatting information that keeps the spellcheck from working.  Now you lose formatting which is not always wanted.  I have done this when pasting code samples into word for whatever reason.

Comment: I've tried doing a past-special and trying the different options there, but it's still bringing the formatting over.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a language issue?

To check, select the text, go to the Review tab, and in the Proofing section, click the "Set Language" command. (If your window is too small to show the command name, the icon looks like a globe with a red checkmark next to it.) Make sure the language is one for which you have spelling dictionaries, and make sure the "Do not check spelling or grammar" checkbox at the bottom is not marked.